# UPDATE: re Java ArrayList and method return

Tags: java, arraylist, printing, return

Below is my code and the print method is in the first class (Hyrestagare) as "public String address()".

I keep reading similar questions and answers in Stackoverflow. But I just get more confused. I make changes to the code, rewrite parts, but just can't solve the problem. :(

Comment: Please **read** [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and explain **how** the output you get doesn't match your **desired** output. Also, explain what steps you've taken to research and debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would not recommend returning `null` ever, it just makes dealing with `NullPointerExceptions` even harder.

regarding your problem:

```
public String address(){
    for (Hus h : houses){
        return h.getAddress();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem here is in your example above, you create an instance of `Hyrestagare` called `a1` but you never add any houses to this class.

Thats why when you later call `a1.address()`, your array of houses is empty, so it just `returns null;`.

As you use an `ArrayList`of Hus you will have multiple addresses. The problem with your approach, you will only get the element of the first address, because you return (escape out of the functions) the value.

Depending on what your goal with this function is, i could offer you some solutions:

1) This would return all addresses as a new list. If there where no addresses, than you will get an empty list and don't have to deal with null.

```
public List<String> getAddresses(List<Hus> list){
    return list.stream()
            .map(Hus::getAddress)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If this solution is to complex for you, this gives you the same result with simpler code:

```
public List<String> getAddresses(List<Hus> list){
    List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Hus h: list){
        addresses.add(h.getAddress());
    }
    return addresses;
}
```

But if you just want the first address, like in your code (If intended or not):

```
public static String getAddress(List<Hus> list){
    if(list.isEmpty()){
        return "no address";
    } else {
        return list.get(0).getAddress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method solved it! However on the exercise paper the professor specifies writing the method as "public String address()" and he wants it to return null if there's not available address... which confuses me even more.

Comment: well you can of course return null, but then you would have to do the check in your print method like:
   `String address = a1.address(); ` and when you print it: `System.out.print(address  != null? address : "");` This is just a shortened if <condition>? true: false

Answer (score 0):

In `Hyrestagare` class, `address()` method calls `getAddress()` on `Hus` object, however, there is no `setAddress()` call in `Demo` class and hence, address remains `null`, try the following:

```
    Hyrestagare a1 = new Hyrestagare();
    a1.setNamn("Donald");
    a1.setPersonnummer(111);

    Hyrestagare a2 = new Hyrestagare();
    a2.setNamn("Ivanka");
    a2.setPersonnummer(222);

    Hyrestagare b1 = new Hyrestagare();
    b1.setNamn("Barack");
    b1.setPersonnummer(333);

    Hyrestagare b2 = new Hyrestagare();
    b2.setNamn("Michelle");
    b2.setPersonnummer(444);

    Lagenhet l1 = new Lagenhet();
    l1.setHyra(5000);
    l1.setNummer(1);
    l1.setYta(200);

    Lagenhet l2 = new Lagenhet();
    l2.setHyra(2000);
    l2.setNummer(2);
    l2.setYta(50);

    Hus hus1 = new Hus();
    hus1.setAddress("Test Address");//sets the address

    // HYRESTAGARE KOPPLA TILL LAGENHET
    a1.setLagenhet(l1);
    a2.setLagenhet(l1);
    b1.setLagenhet(l2);
    b2.setLagenhet(l2);

    // LAGENHET KOPPLA HYRESTAGARE TILL LAGENHET, KOPPLA LISTA TILL LAGENHET
    ArrayList<Hyrestagare> renters = new ArrayList<Hyrestagare>();
    l1.laggTillHyrestagare(a1);
    l1.laggTillHyrestagare(a2);
    l2.laggTillHyrestagare(b1);
    l2.laggTillHyrestagare(b2);

    l1.setRenter(renters);
    l2.setRenter(renters);

    renters.add(a1);
    renters.add(a2);
    renters.add(b1);
    renters.add(b2);

    // HUS KOPPLA LAGENHET TILL LISTA
    ArrayList<Lagenhet> flats = new ArrayList<Lagenhet>();
    hus1.laggTillLagenhet(l1);
    hus1.laggTillLagenhet(l2);

    hus1.setApartments(flats);
    flats.add(l1);
    flats.add(l2);

    // KOPPLA HUS TILL HUS LISTA
    ArrayList<Hus> buildings = new ArrayList<Hus>();
    buildings.add(hus1);

    // PRINT METODER
    for (Hyrestagare temp : hus1.printHyrestagare(1)){
        System.out.println("Hyrestagare: " + temp.getNamn() + " (" + temp.getPersonnummer() + ").");
    }

    for (Hyrestagare temp : hus1.printHyrestagare(2)){
        System.out.println("Hyrestagare: " + temp.getNamn() + " (" + temp.getPersonnummer() + ").");
    }

    System.out.println("Address: " + a1.address());
```

Comment: I tried it however it still prints out "Address: null" :/